# Why I need the: "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

Somebody can explain to me for what this link: `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` is necessary.

for example:

```
public class Demo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String driverName = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";

        try {
            // loaded the driver
            Class.forName(driverName);

            System.out.println("driver loaded");

            String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db1";

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it helps me, thanks Mark

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary, and hasn't been since Java 6. The [JDBC 4.0-only features](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html) says (in part)

> **Autoloading of JDBC drivers.** In earlier versions of JDBC, applications had to manually register drivers before requesting Connections. With JDBC 4.0, applications no longer need to issue a `Class.forName()` on the driver name; instead, the `DriverManager` will find an appropriate JDBC driver when the application requests a `Connection`.

In earlier versions of Java, it was required to load (and register) the JDBC driver.

Comment: :), First, I like to thank you. If you can present me some a little of the code, that substitutes of my presented ways (String driverName = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver") I thank you again ).